# Shir Lamaalot and not Shir Hamaalot for psalm 121?

Tags: tehilim-psalms

Why do all the Shir Hamaalot’s in Tehillim begin with שיר המעלות except for [Psalm 121](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.121.1?lang=bi) which begins שיר למעלות? What’s different about this psalm from the rest of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.121.1?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Psalms.121.1.2&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) there, who makes your observation and quotes the Sifri who says it is phrased as it is because it is a reward of the righteous in the World to Come:

> שיר למעלות. רמז במזמור שני למעלות העולות לצדיקים לעתיד לבא מתחת עץ החיים לכסא הכבוד דתניא בספרי **שיר המעלות אין כתוב כאן אלא שיר למעלות שיר למי שעתיד לעשות מעלות לצדיקים לעתיד לבא**, וזהו שיסד הקליר (בסילוק דיוצר של יום ב' דסוכות שיסד ר' אליעזר הקליר שהוא בנו של רשב"י בחגיגה פ' אין דורשין ע"ש) ומתחתיה שלשים מעלות זו למעלה מזו עד כסא הכבוד טסות ועולות בשיח נעימות שיר המעלות:
>
> A song for ascents [The Psalmist] alludes, in the second psalm, to the steps that ascend for the righteous in the future from beneath the tree of life to the Throne of Glory, as we learned in [Sifrei (Ekev 47)](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Devarim.47.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en): **“It does not say here, ‘A song of ascents’ but, ‘A song for ascents’; a song for the One Who is destined to make ascents for the righteous in the future.”** This is what the Kalir established (in the concluding poem of the morning service for the second day of Succoth, which was composed by Rabbi Elazar the son of Rabbi Simon the son of Yochai in Chagigah, chapter “We may not expound,” see there): “And from beneath them thirty steps, one above the other until the Throne of Glory, flying and ascending with the pleasant speech of the song of ascents.”

Rav Tzvi Elimelech of Dinov in his [Agra DePirka 227](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=4280&st=&pgnum=35&hilite=) explains that the "lamed" is a reference to the ל' מעלות - the 30 heights that a Jewish king attains (Refer to [Pirkei Avos 6:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.6.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) "שֶׁהַמַּלְכוּת נִקְנֵית בִּשְׁלֹשִׁים מַעֲלוֹת" - "Royalty is acquired by thirty stages"). The king earns the right to ascend these heights only by him first lowering himself with sincere humility.

Comment: Still a little confused about what “ascents” even means and about this answer (I see it’s the right answer I’m just not khopping it). And still why davka psalm 121 that uses this phrase and not any of the other ones?